# .net entity framework many to many

Tags: .net, entity-framework, checkbox, many-to-many

I have these models like these

```
clients(id,name,address)
cars(id,platenum)
client_cars(clientid,carid)
```

What I would like to do is add `cars` to a `client` and the data would be saved to the `client_cars` table. Where the form to add the data would have checkboxes of plate numbers. Does anyone know any good examples that accomplish this kind of idea?

Comment: There are good examples of defining many to many relationships in both Model First and Code First EF. Not sure you'll find any UI examples though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this example and it answers my question: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

With EF, your conceptual model shouldn't have the many-many table. It is only in the store model. Your objects should look more like this:

```
clients(id,name,address, cars[])
cars(id,platenum, clients[])
```

In the UI, you would typically have a Client form that includes the client info and a list of the cars. In addition, your Car for

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the example within SimpleMembership, which has:

**Role**

```
[Table("webpages_Roles")]//3
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Members = new List<Membership>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Membership> Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Membership**

```
[Table("webpages_Membership")]//1
public class Membership
{
    public Membership()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
        OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }

    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }

    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

**UsersInRole**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
          .HasMany<Role>(r => r.Roles)
          .WithMany(u => u.Members)
          .Map(m =>
          {
              m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
              m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
              m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
          });
    }
```

Sorry, i could have made code simpler but i didn't want to alter anything from original classes. But this pretty much should give you an idea on how to do it.